# iPhone - is ASIHTTPRequest threadsafe?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, thread-safety, asihttprequest

I have this method:

```
-(void)updateSomething
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some url"];

   ASIFormDataRequest *httpRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [httpRequest startSynchronous];
   //some other stuff
   [pool drain];
}
```

I call this method on`applicationDidFinishLaunching`
IF i call it on the main thread it works fine

```
[self getMyItems];
```

But when I call it on a separate thread I get a "Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getMyItems) withObject:nil];
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why perform individual requests on separate threads when you can use ASINetworkQueue?

```
ASINetworkQueue *aQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];
[aQueue addOperation:requestToAdd];
[aQueue setDelegate:self];
[aQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[aQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
[aQueue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueFinished:)];
[aQueue go];
```

`ASINetworkQueue` is a subclass of `NSOperationQueue` and ASI*Requests are run on separate threads.